# Select and save specific sheets as new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I need to write a macro that allows me to select which workbook sheets I want to save as a new file separately.

I am currently doing it with the following code, but it saves all the sheets as a new file. I would like to be able to select or define which sheets I want to save.

```
Sub Save_sheets_xlsx()

Dim Path As String
Path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

Dim FileName As String
FileName = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 5)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each xWs In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    xWs.Copy
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=Path & "\" & FileName & " " & xWs.Name & ".xlsx"
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    
Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You can use `ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs (FileName)` to save complete copy, open it and delete the other sheets and save again.

Comment: How many files are involved in your code i.e. is ActiveWorkbook the same as ThisWorkbook? If not, what is the purpose of the ActiveWorkbook (I mean the ActiveWorkbook before the loop)?

Answer (score 1):

### Export Sheets As New Workbooks

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ExportSheets()
    
    Const SheetNameList As String = "Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3" ' commas no spaces!

    Dim SheetNames() As String: SheetNames = Split(SheetNameList, ",")
    Dim FolderPath As String: FolderPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
    Dim BaseName As String
    BaseName = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, Len(ThisWorkbook.Name) - 5)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
    Dim sh As Object
    Dim FilePath As String
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetNames)
        sh.Copy
        FilePath = FolderPath & "\" & BaseName & " " & sh.Name & ".xlsx"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
        Workbooks(Workbooks.Count).SaveAs FileName:=FilePath
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Sheets exported.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Sir, fast & accuracy is 1OO%. Worked for me perfectly! Thank you !